# css animation resets after animation

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, animation, transform, css-animations

i'm not to sure if its the bootstrap framework or that i'm missing something but this animation is meant to rotate various states of the letter **Y**.

```
h2 .rotateY, li .rotateY{

  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards; /*when the spec is finished*/
  animation: animationFrames ease-in-out 2s;


  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation: animationFrames ease-in-out 2s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards; /*Chrome 16+, Safari 4+*/ 


  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards; /*FF 5+*/
  -moz-animation: animationFrames ease-in-out 2s;


  -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -o-animation-fill-mode:forwards; /*Not implemented yet*/
  -o-animation: animationFrames ease-in-out 2s;


  -ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -ms-animation-fill-mode:forwards; /*IE 10+*/
  -ms-animation: animationFrames ease-in-out 2s;
}

@keyframes animationFrames{
  0% {

    transform:  rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {

    transform:  rotate(180deg) ;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes animationFrames{
  0% {

    -moz-transform:  rotate(180deg);
  }
  100% {

    -moz-transform:  rotate(180deg) ;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animationFrames {
  0% {

    -webkit-transform:  rotate(0deg) ;
  }
  100% {

    -webkit-transform:  rotate(180deg) ;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes animationFrames {
  0% {

    -o-transform:  rotate(180deg) ;
  }
  100% {

    -o-transform:  rotate(180deg) ;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes animationFrames {
  0% {

    -ms-transform:  rotate(180deg) ;
  }
  100% {

    -ms-transform:  rotate(180deg) ;
  }
}
```

the end result **should be** an upside-down Y after going through 180 degrees rotation.

i'm getting the animation working but after its ran, the **Y** snaps back to the correct orientation.

The reason for this upside-down **Y** is a design with typography. using this as an image is not practical.

incidentally, the respective html code for this issue, within a few divs, is:

```
<h2>H<span class="rotateY">Y</span>BRID</h2>
```

Comment: Have you tried having it always be upside down( add transform: rotate(180deg);) from the beginning to the actual element  and animate it without a delay. Because you're telling the upright element to rotate, and when it's finished, just resume position. So have it resume transform: rotate(180deg)

Comment: you mean...

    'transform: rotate(180deg);'

at the top of the css?

Comment: It stays at upside down position for me and `forwards` setting is supposed to make it retain its state as of the last keyframe. Are you sure there is nothing over-riding it? Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/RF64A/).

Comment: There's nothing overriding it - as soon as the animation ends, it's going to resume what it was doing before unless it has a iteration of infinite. Check out http://jsfiddle.net/sP9q4/

Comment: not sure harry, i assume there is an issue through bootstrap then

Comment: Yeah, that looks awesome - but fillmode is quirky below ie10.

Comment: evan, your rotate has flipped the whole element/page.

part of the result i was looking for was that its location is the same, but Y is upside-down

Comment: You wouldn't want to add it at the top of the css, you would want to add it to .rotateY. http://jsfiddle.net/aVN53/

Comment: @Harry http://jsfiddle.net/27m2c/

Comment: @ShowcaseImagery: Check if [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/27m2c/1/) works for you. Transforms like rotate etc will work only on block/inline-block elements so I just modified the display property.

Comment: not bad @Harry though its lost its alignment

Comment: @ShowcaseImagery: True, but that could be overcome with a little translate hack like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/27m2c/2/). I have removed some of the older comments to keep the discussion short.

Comment: so just to clarify @Harry using the inline-block is what go it resolved. But that doesnt permit me to have a non-animated version with the upside-down Y....does it?

Comment: Did not get you mate. If you want a version without animation you just need to remove the animation property setting.

Comment: hey @Harry this doesnt work in a list!

'li .hybrid {
    display:inline;
    transform:rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(180deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg); /* Opera, Chrome, and Safari */ 
    -o-transform:rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(180deg);
}'

Comment: @ShowcaseImagery: It does work mate. Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/27m2c/4/).